# how to drag only header in syncfusion scheduler dialog

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, drag, syncfusion

net core C# syncfusion scheduler.

I made my scheduler's dialog draggable

```
        function OnPopupOpen(args) {

        var dragElement = document.getElementById('schedule_dialog_wrapper');
        var draggable = new ej.base.Draggable(dragElement, { clone: false });
```

but I want make drag only I drag the header
but my dialog is draggable anywhere... like this...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1obbc0ti8TgWrG6U8A9igqLtxE0fIKMor/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make drag only when drag the header of dialog instead of full dialog by using the Dialog’s [allowDragging](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/aspnetcore-js2/syncfusion.ej2.popups.dialog.html#Syncfusion_EJ2_Popups_Dialog_AllowDragging) property in the Schedule’s [popupOpen](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/aspnetcore-js2/syncfusion.ej2.schedule.schedule.html#Syncfusion_EJ2_Schedule_Schedule_PopupOpen) event, as shown in the below shared snippet.

**allowDragging UG:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/dialog/getting-started#draggable

**Demo**: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Dialog/Draggable#/fluent

```
function onPopupOpen(args) 
{
    var dialogInstance = document.querySelector(".e-dialog").ej2_instances[0];
    dialogInstance. allowDragging = true;
}
```

Comment: omg you made it!!!
I have another question...

when first time my popup open -> It is open where center center
but after I dragged popup and open again -> It open where I dragged ...

so I did this code

   ' var dialogInstance = document.querySelector(".e-dialog").ej2_instances[0];
    dialogInstance. allowDragging = true;

    dialogInstance.position = { X : 'center' , Y : 'center' }; '

but It didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the position API, you can use the refresh method to achieve your requirement, as shown in the below shared snippet.

```
 function onPopupOpen(args) 
 {

 var dialogInstance = document.querySelector(".e-dialog").ej2_instances[0];

 dialogInstance.allowDragging = true;   

 dialogInstance.target = '.e-schedule';

 dialogInstance.refresh();

}
```